# Display video using mysql and php on web browser

Tags: php, mysql, html5-video

I am trying to display a video on Microsoft Edge web browser but i'm getting some errors like:
HTTP “Content-Type” of “text/html” is not supported. Load of media resource http://localhost/File path/ failed.

Specified “type” attribute of “video.ogg” is not supported. Load of media resource ../videos/ failed.

All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused.

I have inserted both .mp4 and .ogg video types in my database. And used the code below to display the videos but only the controls can be seen the video is not playing.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbName = "movie review";

//create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);


if($conn->connect_error){
  die("Connection Failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Description</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    //Create Query
$search =  'SELECT id, name FROM movie_video ORDER BY id';

//Execute query
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $search);

// if there is no result display the following
if(!$result){
    echo ("No video found in database!");
    exit();
}

//Display the number of records found
echo ("<p>The query found " . mysqli_num_rows($result) . " videos.</p>");

// loop through the records found

while($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo("<video controls>  <source src=../videos/ type=video/mp4 />
        <source src=../videos/ type=video.ogg />" . $record['name'] . "</video>");
        
}



?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<source src=../videos/ type=video/mp4 />` -- There's no file name here.

Comment: Actually yes that was my mistake thanks!!

Comment: Do you have any idea on how i could on link click, query my database and display a corresponding video?